Probability $P(T>t)$ as Integral
Let $T$ be an $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$-distributed random variable for some $\lambda>0$, and let $Y := T \wedge t = \min(T, t)$ for some fixed $t>0$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda t} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \mathbb{P}(T>t) = \int_{\{T>t\}} \frac{1}{\lambda} \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} = \int_{Y^{-1}(B)} \frac{1}{\lambda} \mathbb{1}_{\{T>t\}} \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}
$$
QUESTION: How exactly do we arrive at the last two integrals? What is the fundamental idea that allows this transformation to be made?
There is more context, but it's quite lengthy. However, you might need the following transformation:
$$
Y^{-1}(B) \cap \{T>t\} = \{Y \in B\} \cap \{T>t\} = \{T \wedge t \in B\} \cap \{T>t\} = \{t \in B\} \cap \{T>t\}
$$
If you need me to post the whole problem with context, just let me know.

The first integral is just that$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\int_A\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}$$for any $\mathbb{P}$-measurable set $A$
